# Javascript sum of items in a complex object

Tags: javascript

I have some data that I'm counting and putting the totals into an array.

Here is the data and code:

```
var data = {
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "name 1",
            "thsub": [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "name": "sub 1",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "ions": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "22",
                    "name": "sub 2",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "name 2",
                        "thsub": [
                {
                    "id": "33",
                    "name": "sub 43",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 20,
                    },
                    "ions": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "44",
                    "name": "sub 76",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        }
    ]
}



var thCount = [];

for(key in data.cars[0].thsub ){
  if(data.cars[0].thsub[key].stats){
   thCount.push(data.cars[0].thsub[key].stats.items);
  }
}

console.log(thCount);
```

For some reason "thCount" is returning [5, 5] when the result should be: **[10, 25]**

where is the code going wrong?

Comment: Your code only looks at `data.cars[0]`. It doesn't look at `data.cars[1]`.

Comment: In edition to @Pointy's point, how do you expect [10, 25]? You're not actually summing anything (assuming that's the intention)

Comment: By counting the items field and adding them up

Comment: Where does your code even *try* to perform any addition of numbers?

Comment: @PaulTenna2000, have a look to my method in order to write a more easy solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another loop on cars.

```js
var data = {
  "cars": [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "name 1",
      "thsub": [{
        "id": "11",
        "name": "sub 1",
        "stats": {
          "items": 5,
        },
        "ions": null
      }, {
        "id": "22",
        "name": "sub 2",
        "stats": {
          "items": 5,
        },
        "translations": null
      }],
      "image": null
    },

    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "name 2",
      "thsub": [{
        "id": "33",
        "name": "sub 43",
        "stats": {
          "items": 20,
        },
        "ions": null
      }, {
        "id": "44",
        "name": "sub 76",
        "stats": {
          "items": 5,
        },
        "translations": null
      }],
      "image": null
    }
  ]
}



var thCount = [];

for (var l = 0, m = data.cars.length; l < m; l++) {
  thCount[l] = 0;
  for (var i = 0, j = data.cars[l].thsub.length; i < j; i++) {
    if (data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats) {
      thCount[l]+=data.cars[l].thsub[i].stats.items;
    }
  }
}

console.log(thCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for your problem is as pasted below:

```
**var count = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.cars.length; i++){
   countSum = 0;     
   for(key in data.cars[i].thsub){
            countSum = countSum + data.cars[i].thsub[key].stats.items;
    }   
    count.push(countSum); 
}**
```

Try this code, will solve your problem.

Comment: You should explain a bit about how this work, not only paste the answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah Ivan sure. Ivan you were just missing the other array values of data.cars array.

Comment: So, I am just first parsing the data.cars array in the first for loop. and then adding the values of each stats.items I am able to fetch from data.cars[index.....n] to countSum variable and pushing every countSum to respective count array variable index..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reduce()` and `map()` methods.Any of this using a `callback` function.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.
>
> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```
var result=data.cars.map(function(item){
     return item.thsub.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.stats.items + b.stats.items; });
});
```

```js
var data = {
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "name 1",
            "thsub": [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "name": "sub 1",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "ions": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "22",
                    "name": "sub 2",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "name 2",
                        "thsub": [
                {
                    "id": "33",
                    "name": "sub 43",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 20,
                    },
                    "ions": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "44",
                    "name": "sub 76",
                    "stats": {
                        "items": 5,
                    },
                    "translations": null
                }
            ],
            "image": null
        }
    ]
}
console.log(data.cars.map(function(item){
  return item.thsub.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.stats.items + b.stats.items; });
}));
```